# registration -> send data to two tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

on registration i register a user to two tables - Users and Companies. Company.php and User.php have a relationship as you can see in code bellow.

in AuthController.php i use " `'user_id' => $user['id'],` to pass id of new created row in users table to companies table. 
i know  its somehow wrong but it works and i just want to know how could i create two rows at the same time with foreign key in much smarter way.
i just think that i dont use that relationship properly though

**company.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Company extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'ICO', 'user_id',
    ];
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable {
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'usertype',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function company() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Company');
    }
}
```

**AuthController.php** --> protected function create(array $data)

```
protected function create(array $data) {
        $user = User::create([
                    'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
                    'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
                    'middlename' => $data['middlename'],
                    'usertype' => $data['usertype'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        $company = Company::create([
                    'ICO' => $data['ICO'],
                    'user_id' => $user['id'],
        ]);
        return $user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The store function in your main controller should be something similar to the following:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

        $user = new User;
        $user->firstname = $request->get('firstname');
        $user->lastname = $request->get('lastname');
        $user->middlename = $request->get('middlename');
        $user->usertype = $request->get('usertype');
        $user->email = $request->get('email');
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));

        $user->save();

        $company = new Company;
        $company->ICO = $request->get('ICO');
        $company->user_id = Auth::id();

        $company->save();
        $user->company()->save($company);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I didn't test this code, however this should give you some insight on how you can use it in a smarter way, with your current models. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: do i need to write a brand new store function or just edit my create method in same way?

Comment: You have to add this code in the store method of your main controller if you have any, remove the code from AuthController.php @miiisapiiisa

Comment: no i dont have, do i need one ?  https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#included-authenticating , -> are you really sure?